# Spark streaming example not working for me : Network word count (maybe Data not getting streamed)

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

1. Started master and worker
2. Started a console and entered

> nc -lk 9999

3. Ran Network word count example

> ./bin/run-example streaming.NetworkWordCount localhost 9999

4. Wrote  in

> "Hello world Hello"

netcat console.

5. But the console where I ran program , did not show the computed data(may be data did not get streamed), when I stopped program , it computed

> Hello, 2 
>   world,1

Comment: I'm using spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6 and it works fine for me by following your steps. Before, I had the same problem, but that's because I run the example before I run nc -lk 9999.

Comment: I believe it has to do nothing with the hadoop version ? . My spark version is spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.4 while the underlying hadoop version is hadoop-2.6

Answer (score 6):

I too faced the same problem and spent last weekend in order to get this simple streaming example to work. Finally I could able to execute NetworkWorkCount program successfully. I am using spark 1.5.2. and Ubuntu_14 System.

There are multiple ways in order to solve this issue, You can use either one of them :

1. You need to update the code of NetworkWorkCount.scala (inside /examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/), Add setMaster("local[2]") while creating SparkConf variable as follows.

   new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("NetworkWordCount")

Problem with this approach is, You've to somehow compile this updated code in order to get our modification effective which might be another issue for the people who just started learning spark and trying their hand to run this simple example. For them the easiest way is below option.

2. Easiest solution is to set MASTER variable to local[2] as follows :

   a. Change to /conf directory of your SPARK_HOME

   b. Create spark-env.sh using the provided template :

   ```
    cp spark-env.sh.template spark-env.sh
   ```

   Open spark-env.sh and set following configuration in it:

   ```
    MASTER=local[2]
   ```
3. Now open first terminal and start netcat utility

   > nc -lk 9999
4. Open second terminal and execute NetworkWordCount program

   > ./bin/run-example streaming.NetworkWordCount localhost 9999

It will start showing continuous streaming as follows :

```
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1450077999000 ms
-------------------------------------------
(are,12)
(am,6)
(how,6)
(rashmit,6)
(apache,6)
(hello,5)
(spark,5)
(you,12)
(i,6)
(sparkhello,1)
...

-------------------------------------------
Time: 1450078000000 ms
-------------------------------------------
(are,2)
(am,1)
(how,1)
(rashmit,1)
(apache,1)
(hello,1)
```

Comment: Any idea why the example has this fault?  Does it default to a single thread and lock up?

Comment: Thank you for the tip on local[2] instead of local.  Seems that streaming locks up when data arrives if i run it on one process

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
./bin/run-example --master local[4] streaming.NetworkWordCount localhost 9999
```

Answer (score -1):

We do not need any code change or configuration change to run this example. I faced this problem when trying to run this example in a Virtual Machine.  This problem does not occur when we run the same as part of host machine. Thanks for Rashmit Rathod for clues about this problem.

> Solution is to add "--master local[2]" as part of the run-example command line as follows

```
./bin/run-example --master local[2] org.apache.spark.examples.streaming.NetworkWordCount localhost 9999
```